# Getting a JSON value with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get the **malicious** value from a JSON string.

What's a straight forward way of getting this value? Screenshot and code below.

Pastebin: [link](https://pastebin.com/fw2RqKLm)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

```
import json
  
def vt(domain):

  # load json content from file
  with open('vt.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

  # convert from sring to json
  content = json.loads(content)

  # read how many engines detect this domain as malicious 
  malicious = content["data"]["attributes"]["last_analysis_stats"]["malicious"]
            
  
vt("pp-alert.com")
```

Repl.it code: https://repl.it/@MiguelDuarte1/ButteryCanineDonateware

Comment: How did you get the idea to use `[0]` in `content["data"]["attributes"][0]["malicious"]`? I don't see any list in your JSON file. You have to access the correct dictionary key.

Comment: Also, you're missing `["last_analysis_stats"]`

Comment: Based on the POST link from the bottom. Also tried ´content["data"]["attributes"]["last_analysis_stats"]["malicious"]´ without success.

Comment: last_analysis_stats doesn't work

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Andre You don't have any lists in your path from JSON to your field. Are you sure your objects are similar to the one you shared here?

Comment: It runs for me with `malicious = content["data"]["attributes"]["last_analysis_stats"]["malicious"]`. You might access the wrong file. Please be aware that you open the file from the working directory which might be or not be the same as the one where your script is.

Comment: If you want to make sure that you access the file in the same folder as the script then `import pathlib` and construct the full path to the file like this: `filename = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'vt.txt'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
  
def vt(domain):

  # load json content from file
  with open('vt.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

  # convert from sring to json
  content = json.loads(content)

  # read how many engines detect this domain as 
  malicious = content['data'][0]['attributes']['last_analysis_stats']['malicious']
  #print(malicious)        
  
vt("pp-alert.com")
```

This will give you the result.

Note: the JSON in Pastebin link you have provided is different than that you actually use in the vt.txt file.

Comment: Thanks man! Really worked... thanks for helping a total stranger :-) +1

Comment: We're always eager to help. But please make sure, that you give us correct information. As @KokulJose said: This code won't run with the JSON file you provided in the pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a field, you don't need `[0]` since `attributes` is not an array.
Please try:

```
malicious = content['data']['attributes']['last_analysis_stats']['malicious']
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Andre I was able to successfully read the malicious field using Ofek Hod's solution. Is there other JSON input that you are trying to read as well?

Comment: See the rep.it: https://repl.it/join/kdcmnmou-miguelduarte1

Comment: This will be the answer if the JSON in Pastebin is the input.